# Finding right yq command

Tags: yq

I have a `yaml` file that looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myName
  namespace: default
data:
  values.yaml: |
    people:
    - namespace: "fred"
      identities:
      - name: "one"
      - name: "two"
    - namespace: "bob"
      identities:
      - name: "one"
```

Now i want to add a third identity to Fred (name: "three"), how do I do this with the `yq` command

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myName
  namespace: default
data:
  values.yaml: |
    people:
    - namespace: "fred"
      identities:
      - name: "one"
      - name: "two"
      - name: "three"
    - namespace: "bob"
      identities:
      - name: "one"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse to `.data."values.yaml"`, and update `|=` it, by interpreting the YAML string using `fromyaml`, then finding those `.people[]` that match the given criteria using `select`, adding `+=` the new item `{"name": "three"}` to their array, and encoding all of it again using `toyaml`:

```bash
yq '.data."values.yaml" |= (
  fromyaml
  | (.people[] | select(.namespace == "fred")).identities += {"name": "three"}
  | toyaml
)'
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myName
  namespace: default
data:
  values.yaml: |
    people:
      - namespace: "fred"
        identities:
          - name: "one"
          - name: "two"
          - name: three
      - namespace: "bob"
        identities:
          - name: "one"
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) v4.35.1

Comment: But if you have instead of 2 namespaces (Fred and bob), you got 30, how can I select the right one without knowing the index number.

Comment: @BrulAapje Updated it to include "fred".